# Filtering dates in PowerShell from CSV input

Tags: date, powershell, csv

I've got a script that's causing me grief, where the where clause in the final pip isn't filtering dates out by the criteria I want.

The script is taking a CSV as an input, and the script parses the dates it finds so that they are in the correct date format.

The dates are then processed in a `Where-Object` clause to select all dates that are from within the past month onwards (all records with dates prior are not included). The problem I'm having is that this filter isn't working, and I'm getting all records included regardless.

My question is, what is wrong with my script and how can I fix this where clause.

Here's the code that correlates directly to the above:

```
    if ($o.'Joined Company') {
        $StartDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($o.'Joined Company','d/MM   /yyyy',$null).ToString("dd/M/yyyy")
        $o.StartDateObj = $StartDate
    } elseif ($o.'Joined Company' -eq '') {
        $o.StartDateObj = $null
    }

    if ($o.'last day of duty') {
        $EndDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($o.'Last Day of Duty','d/MM/yyyy',$null).ToString("dd/M/yyyy")
        $o.EndDateObj = $EndDate
    } elseif ($o.'Last Day of Duty' -eq '') {
        $o.EndDateObj = $null
    }

    Write-Debug ("" + $o.EndDateObj)
    Write-Debug ("" + $o.StartDateObj)
}

$Today = Get-Date
$LastMonth = $Today.AddMonths(-1) 
$obj | Where-Object {$_.Company -like "New Zealand"} |
    Where-Object {($_.EndDateobj -gt $LastMonth) -or ($_.EndDateobj -eq $null)} |
```

It's just a snippit of the full script, which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/335adfa8a04e11f447262e9d40559e63).

Comment: you are filtering `$obj` but the dates are in `$o`? Likely this clause is always true `$_.EndDateobj -eq    $null` which is why you get the results you see

Comment: Ah, sorry, probably should have shown the full loop. It's a going through each $o in $obj, and the $null value is there to replace all blank cells (people who haven't been terminated in this case)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question then with that logic. Else there is no other conclusion to draw from what I see. Also would be nice to have some sample input data. My guess is that you are not updating the original object since $o is not a reference. In the end you should see that $obj.EndDateobj is still a string. Assuming it was even a column to begin wiht.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your code, including sample input as well as expected and actual output. Do not post code on external resources that may disappear at any given time, rendering your question useless.

Comment: Turns out I made the silly mistake of comparing date data to a string. I moved the To-String into the Select statement and it fixed it.

Apologies for the formatting mistakes! Will keep that in mind next time.